# Getting error while using swichMap operator for nested subscription in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Error which I am getting is

```
Argument of type '(data: Object) => Observable<Object> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'Observable<Object> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'
```

Follow is the code over which I am facing issue into

```
  this.AService.aFunction(this.parms).pipe(take(1) ,switchMap( data => {
    if(data){
      return this.aService.bDomain(this.parms)
    }
  })
  ).subscribe(result =>{
    if(result){
      open success modal
    } else {
        open fail modal
    }
  })
```

Comment: ... well, it's kinda saying: "ok, inside the SwitchMap, you would handle the `if` condition, continuing the pipeline, .. but what about `else` (in case `if` statement turns out to be `false`)  ..? .. ( I mean, like, return `of(null)` at least of smt ... )

Comment: @Vovan_Super Thanks for the help. Got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switchMap requires an observable, but you only give it an observable `if(data){...`. So all the other times it will fail.

You can either update the `switchMap` to consistently return an observable or you can can filter to keep only the values you want and ignore bad `data` that way.

#### Update `switchMap`

```ts
this.AService.aFunction(this.parms).pipe(

  take(1),
  switchMap(data => {
    if(!!data){
      return this.aService.bDomain(this.parms)
    } else {
      return EMPTY;
    }
  })

).subscribe(result => {
  if(result){
    open success modal
  } else {
    open fail modal
  }
});
```

#### Filter bad `data`

```ts
this.AService.aFunction(this.parms).pipe(

  take(1),
  filter(data => !!data),
  switchMap(data => this.aService.bDomain(this.parms))

).subscribe(result => {
  if(result){
    open success modal
  } else {
    open fail modal
  }
});
```